# Same Aspx Code When I Write In Sharepoint Webpart Page Design Gets a slight change why?

Tags: html, css, .net, sharepoint-2010

Hi all Tech geeks avilable here in the forum,
i am facing some strange problem. I have a aspx page in .net
I just wanted to write the same html code in a sharepoint webpart(same as application page in .net) due to some requirement but doing so i am facing some starnge problem all the design is comming same but the fonts are little increased n size which causing a little differ in style/look of that page.
I cant understand the problem as the whole code is same and all css reference are also same just it has been written in a application page rather than a normal .net web page

kindly copy and paste following link to see the changes in teh page

http://postimg.org/image/p3f79a02f/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the same tags with the different CSS or stylesheets applied in the Sharepoint.  Have a look at the stylesheet applied to the webpart page using Firebug or other developer tools.  If it is the main root cause of a problem, then overwrite the classes in your webpart page or separate stylesheet.